# What version of mscorlib.dll (and the other .NET Framework files) do I have

Tags: .net, runtime, version

I am trying to track down an issue I have with an application.

The Application targets .NET 4.0 and is currently being run on a Windows 7 environment with Service Pack 1.  It is being run from a Shared Network Folder (UNC).

The same user uses 2 PCs to access the application.  1 works fine, the other throws an OutOfMemoryException (which is out of the scope of this post).  My first step is to determine what is different environment wise.

I log all of the DLL information loaded when the application starts up to a file.

**Working Environment**

```
Application Version:    1.9.0.0
Operating System:   Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll  4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\TheApplication.exe   1.9.0.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\NLog.dll 2.1.0.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll   4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\nHydrate.EFCore.dll  5.1.2.122
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll  11.0.50938.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll   4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
```

**Faulty Environment**

```
Application Version:    1.9.0.0
Operating System:   Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 (64-bit)

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll  4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\TheApplication.exe   1.9.0.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\NLog.dll 2.1.0.0
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll   4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
\\TheMachineShare\TheAppFolder\nHydrate.EFCore.dll  5.1.2.122
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualBasic\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll  10.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll 4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll   4.0.30319.1 built by: RTMRel
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
```

Given the information above, can I determine where this Microsoft Framework files come from?  Which Service Pack, .NET Runtime, or Patch or Hotfix?

Comment: Revision 1, that's the original release version of .NET 4.0.  There have been *many* updates and security patches since then.  That machine needs to have Windows Update turned on.  Otherwise very unlikely to have anything to do with OOM.  Not allowing the app to run in 64-bit mode is of course a waste.

Comment: Revision as in the last digit - xxx.xxx.xxx.1?  Ok that's a good start thanks Hans.

Comment: @HansPassant - Are there any online references for versions?

Comment: No.  Just googling the string gets you a long way.